# How to match italic wiki markers but not inside wiki links

Tags: javascript, regex, mediawiki

I need to match strings like this: `''foo''` but not when inside wiki links like: `[[GNU Lesser General Public License|GNU ''Lesser'' General Public License]]`

My try is this but it don't work:

```
/''([^']*(?:'[^']+)*(?![^\]]+\]\]))''/g
```

Comment: Don't use regex. This isn't regular enough. I'd suggest something like http://pegjs.org/, which can be pretty light to start with.

Comment: Use [`\[\[.*?\]\]|''(.*?)''`](https://regex101.com/r/wG3jA5/1) and extract captured group #1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can try with

> ''(.*?)''(?!(?:[^\[]*]{2}))

If you don't wanna matches double quoted string 
with brackets inside of it, you could use:

> ''([^\[\]]*?)''(?!(?:[^\[]*]{2}))

but, beware: Can fails with nested brackets, like:

`[[ ''foo'' aksjdhkajd [[ asdasdasd ]] ]]`

and close brackets without open ones, like:

`asdkjakldha ''akjdhkajdhksd'' ajsdlasjdlasd ]]`

Javascript doesn't support *lookbehind*;
*lookbehind* could enhance the regex.

Take a look on this: http://regexr.com/3cigm

Answer (score 0):

I've decide that process italic text inside links using this code:

```
text = text.replace(/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/g, function(_, gr) {
    gr = gr.split('|');
    if (gr.length == 1) {
        // normal wiki link
    } else {
        // wikilink with name and caption
        gr[1] = gr[1].replace(/''([^']+)''/gm, function(_, g) {
            // g is italic text
        });
        // gr[1] can contain italic text gr[0] is a link
    }
})
```